# PostgreSQL Default Unpassworded Account

Tags: postgresql

I've a PostgreSQL database and our internal vulnerability tool complaining about `Default Unpassworded Account`.
The problem that I can't realize which account unpassworded. I've created a few accounts but everyone has password. `postgres` account has password too.

When I perform : `psql template1 -c '\du'` I got the following output:

```
                              List of roles
  Role name   |                   Attributes                   | Member of
--------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 account1     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB              | {}
 account2     |                                                | {}
 postgres     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 account3     | Password valid until infinity                  | {}
 account4     | Password valid until infinity                  | {}
```

Any advices how to resolve this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: Which check does your vulnerability tool run against your DB?

Comment: Actually I don't know, I only get email with finding and requirement to solve this issue

Comment: Check `pg_hba.conf`. Whether a password is required/prompted for depends on the connection type (TCP or UNIX socket), origin host, and current user too.

Comment: This is a cross-post of http://stackoverflow.com/q/42607493/398670

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like I have found the solution, thanks to this SO topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641823/check-if-a-role-in-postgresql-has-a-password-set

When I issued `select * from pg_shadow;`

```
  usename    | usesysid | usecreatedb | usesuper | usecatupd | userepl |               passwd                | valuntil | useconfig
--------------+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+---------+-------------------------------------+----------+-----------
 postgres     |    16384 | f           | f        | f         | f       |                                     | infinity |
 account1     |    17513 | f           | f        | f         | f       |                                     | infinity |
 account2     |    17679 | f           | f        | f         | f       | 11111111111111111111111111111111111 |          |
 account3     |       10 | t           | t        | t         | t       | 11111111111111111111111111111111111 |          |
 account4     |    16385 | t           | t        | t         | f       | 11111111111111111111111111111111111 |          |
(5 rows)
```

So, roles `postgres` and `account1` indeed didn't have the passwords.

Updated password for these accounts by: `ALTER ROLE postgres WITH PASSWORD 'mysuperstrongpasswordhere';`

And it looks like now everything is ok.